# What does the "-y" do in "yum -y groupinstall gnome"?

Tags: centos, rhel

I've been googling and reading tutorials, but while the authors go into detail with all the things you can do with yum, no one ever mentions what the -y flag is for. I'm trying to automate this with Chef, so I needed to know what the -y does so I can determine whether to include it in my Chef recipe.

Comment: Ever heard of the `man` command? It can come handy at times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the `-y` option with yum, yum will automatically answer "yes" to any question prompt during the operation.  For the example `yum -y groupinstall gnome`, yum may normally ask if you want to follow through with downloading the gnome group of packages.  With `-y` present, yum automatically answers yes to this question.

From the [`man` page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/yum8.html):

> -y        Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question  which 
>   would
>                 be asked is yes.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply-I'm marking this as the answer.